# CLLocationManager class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cllocationmanager

can CLLocationManager class be used to compute the distsnce travelled by the person?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but `CLLocation` objects can.  If you have two locations, then you can easily use the [`-[CLLocation distanceFromLocation:]`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007126-CH3-SW18) method to get the distance between them.  Note, however, that this distance will be from along a [great circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle) ("as the crow flies"), and *not* along any roads in the area.